# Is there a limit for Android Studio's Native Memory Profiler recording?

Tags: android-studio, android-profiler, android-studio-electric-eel

If I use [Android Studio's Native Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#native-memory-profiler) to record native memory allocation, it works fine if I record for a minute or so. However, I get the following if I view a recording that is long (e.g., more than 5 minutes):
[image]
I have got this "Selected capture has no contents" many times. At one time, I got this for a recording of a little over 1 minute.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unexpected behavior. You can file a bug through Help -> Submit Feedback explaining the issue along with the trace file.